How can I get the logged in user profile in Kivy?
I'm new in Kivy, and now I'm developing an application. I was able to create sign up and the sign in functions.
When the user is connected, I would like, when he clic on profile button to be able to display all his information details such as username, firstname, ...
However, the page is empty knowing it shouldn't be because the user is created successfully and are able to log in.
This is the function that I would like to be assisted in order to get the logged in user's details for modification if needed:
# account_page.py
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineIconListItem, IconLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigation, MDBottomNavigationItem
from db_utils import get_db_connection

class AccountPage(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.build_ui, 0.1)

    def build_ui(self, dt):
        # Main layout for the content
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=20, spacing=10)

        # List to hold interactive options
        options_list = MDList()

        # Add "Back" item styled as a list item
        back_item = OneLineIconListItem(
            text="Back",
            on_release=self.go_back
        )
        back_item.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon="arrow-left"))
        options_list.add_widget(back_item)

        # Add "Logout" item styled as a list item
        logout_item = OneLineIconListItem(
            text="Logout",
            on_release=self.logout
        )
        logout_item.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon="logout"))
        options_list.add_widget(logout_item)

        # Add "Profile" dropdown item styled as a list item with an arrow icon
        self.profile_item = OneLineIconListItem(
            text="Profile",
            on_release=self.toggle_profile_details
        )
        self.profile_arrow_icon = IconLeftWidget(icon="chevron-down")
        self.profile_item.add_widget(self.profile_arrow_icon)
        options_list.add_widget(self.profile_item)

        # Container for profile details, initially hidden
        self.profile_details_list = MDList()
        self.profile_details_list.opacity = 0  # Hide initially

        # Add the options list to the main layout
        main_layout.add_widget(options_list)

        # Create a scroll view for the user details
        scroll_view = ScrollView()
        self.account_list = MDList()
        self.account_list.add_widget(OneLineIconListItem(text="Loading account details..."))
        scroll_view.add_widget(self.account_list)

        # Add the scroll view and profile details list to the main layout
        main_layout.add_widget(scroll_view)
        main_layout.add_widget(self.profile_details_list)

        # Add Bottom Navigation for Home, Trips History, and Account
        bottom_nav = MDBottomNavigation()

        # Home Tab
        home_tab = MDBottomNavigationItem(
            name='home',
            text='Home',
            icon='home',
            on_tab_press=lambda x: self.switch_screen('home')
        )
        bottom_nav.add_widget(home_tab)

        # Trips History Tab
        trips_tab = MDBottomNavigationItem(
            name='trips',
            text='Trips History',
            icon='history',
            on_tab_press=lambda x: self.switch_screen('trips')
        )
        bottom_nav.add_widget(trips_tab)

        # Account Tab
        account_tab = MDBottomNavigationItem(
            name='account',
            text='Account',
            icon='account',
            on_tab_press=lambda x: self.switch_screen('account')
        )
        bottom_nav.add_widget(account_tab)

        # Add the bottom navigation to the main layout
        main_layout.add_widget(bottom_nav)

        # Add the main layout to the screen
        self.add_widget(main_layout)

        # Fetch and display user details
        self.fetch_and_display_user_details()

    def fetch_and_display_user_details(self):
        """Fetch the user details from the database and display them."""
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        username = app.session.get('username')

        try:
            conn = get_db_connection()
            if not conn:
                self.account_list.add_widget(
                    OneLineIconListItem(text="Database connection failed.")
                )
                return

            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                query = """
                    SELECT username, phone_number, email, wallet_balance 
                    FROM public.users_tb 
                    WHERE username = %s
                """
                cur.execute(query, (username,))
                user_data = cur.fetchone()

                if user_data:
                    fetched_username, phone_number, email, wallet_balance = user_data

                    self.account_list.clear_widgets()

                    # Store fetched data in class variables for editing
                    self.username = fetched_username
                    self.phone_number = phone_number
                    self.email = email
                    self.wallet_balance = wallet_balance

                    # Display account details as editable fields
                    self.username_field = MDTextField(text=fetched_username, hint_text="Username")
                    self.phone_field = MDTextField(text=phone_number, hint_text="Phone Number")
                    self.email_field = MDTextField(text=email, hint_text="Email")

                    # Populate profile details for the dropdown
                    self.profile_details_list.clear_widgets()
                    self.profile_details_list.add_widget(self.username_field)
                    self.profile_details_list.add_widget(self.phone_field)
                    self.profile_details_list.add_widget(self.email_field)

                    # Add "Save" button for profile editing
                    save_button = MDRaisedButton(
                        text="Save Changes",
                        size_hint=(0.5, None),
                        height=50,
                        pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                        on_release=self.save_profile_changes
                    )
                    self.profile_details_list.add_widget(save_button)

                else:
                    self.account_list.add_widget(
                        OneLineIconListItem(text="User details not found.")
                    )

        except Exception as e:
            self.account_list.add_widget(
                OneLineIconListItem(text=f"Error fetching user details: {e}")
            )
        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()

    def toggle_profile_details(self, instance):
        """Toggle the visibility of the profile details."""
        if self.profile_details_list.opacity == 0:
            self.profile_details_list.opacity = 1
            self.profile_arrow_icon.icon = "chevron-up"
        else:
            self.profile_details_list.opacity = 0
            self.profile_arrow_icon.icon = "chevron-down"

    def save_profile_changes(self, instance):
        """Save the edited profile details to the database."""
        username = self.username_field.text
        phone_number = self.phone_field.text
        email = self.email_field.text

        try:
            conn = get_db_connection()
            if not conn:
                self.account_list.add_widget(
                    OneLineIconListItem(text="Database connection failed.")
                )
                return

            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                query = """
                    UPDATE public.users_tb 
                    SET phone_number = %s, email = %s 
                    WHERE username = %s
                """
                cur.execute(query, (phone_number, email, username))
                conn.commit()

                # Update displayed details after saving
                self.fetch_and_display_user_details()
                print("Profile updated successfully!")

        except Exception as e:
            self.account_list.add_widget(
                OneLineIconListItem(text=f"Error updating profile: {e}")
            )
        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()

    def logout(self, instance):
        """Handle user logout and navigate back to the login screen."""
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.clear_session()
        app.switch_screen('login')
        app.login_page.clear_fields()  # Ensure login fields are cleared

    def go_back(self, instance):
        """Navigate back to the previous screen."""
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.switch_screen('home')

    def switch_screen(self, screen_name):
        """Switch to a different screen."""
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        app.switch_screen(screen_name)

Here is the main page's code:
# main.py
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout, MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem
from home_page import HomePage
from account_page import AccountPage
from trips_history_page import TripsHistoryPage
from signup_page import SignUpFormPage, SignUpCredentialsPage
from login_page import LoginPage

# Set window size to simulate mobile phone
Window.size = (360, 640)

class RideShareApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Initialize session dictionary to store user session information
        self.session = {'username': None, 'user_id': None}

        # Create the navigation layout
        self.nav_layout = MDNavigationLayout()

        # Create the navigation drawer
        self.nav_drawer = MDNavigationDrawer()
        drawer_items = MDList()
        for item in ["Profile", "Payment", "Promotions", "My Rides", "Support", "About", "Expense Your Rides"]:
            drawer_items.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=item))

        self.nav_drawer.add_widget(drawer_items)
        self.nav_layout.add_widget(self.nav_drawer)

        # Screen Manager to switch between screens
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        # Add all the pages (screens) to the screen manager
        self.home_page = HomePage(name="home")
        self.account_page = AccountPage(name="account")
        self.trips_history_page = TripsHistoryPage(name="trips")
        self.signup_form_page = SignUpFormPage(name='signup')
        self.signup_credentials_page = SignUpCredentialsPage(name='signup_step2')
        self.login_page = LoginPage(name='login')

        # Add the screens to the screen manager
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.home_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.account_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.trips_history_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.signup_form_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.signup_credentials_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self.login_page)

        # Start with the login page by default
        self.nav_layout.add_widget(self.screen_manager)
        self.switch_screen('login')

        return self.nav_layout

    def switch_screen(self, screen_name):
        if screen_name == 'login':
            # Clear fields when logging out
            self.login_page.clear_fields()
            self.session.clear()  # Clear session data
        self.screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def set_logged_in_user(self, username, user_id):
        """Sets the logged-in user's details in the session."""
        self.session['username'] = username
        self.session['user_id'] = user_id
        print(f"User {username} logged in with user_id: {user_id}")

    def clear_session(self):
        """Clears the user session details upon logout."""
        self.session = {'username': None, 'user_id': None}
        print("User session cleared. Redirecting to login.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        RideShareApp().run()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Application crashed: {e}")

I would like to have an assistance on how I can display the user's details in the account_page.py.
